# How do I activate "while tagging" powers?

Tags: marvel-future-fight

Several of the leadership powers in Marvel Future Fight activate "while tagging."  But the game doesn't say anywhere what Tagging means in this context.

Answer (score 1):

Tagging is the term in game for switching to another character while playing.  Black Widow's speed power has the same duration as the cool down on returning to the previous character, so with two characters you can keep the run buff up.